# why executing a command with ssh works, but assigning it to a var doesn't work?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

the following command works:

```
ssh host ls -1 /home/folder/anotherFolder | wc -l
```

but this one doesnt work:

```
ssh host num=`ls -1 /home/folder/anotherFolder | wc -l`
```

nor this:

```
ssh host num=`ls -1 "/home/folder/anotherFolder" | wc -l`
```

nor this:

```
ssh host num=`ls -1 "/home/folder/anotherFolder" | wc -l`
```

all these return:

```
ls: cannot access /home/folder/anotherFolder: No such file or directory
```

as it was looking for this folder in the client computer rather than in the remote one.

EDIT:
clarification:
I nee to have $num in the ssh context, not outside of it.
The whole ssh command is to check if $num is greater than X and if it does, perform another command on the remote computer, all in a single ssh session.

EDIT2:
Thanks, I've accomplished what I've needed with your help.
The original task is to delete the oldest folder in a remote machine if it has more than X defined folders.
this is what works for me:

```
ssh host "num=\$(ls -1 \$path | wc -l); if [ \$num -gt $num_of_backups ]; then rm -r $backup/\"\$(ls -t1 $backup | tail -n 1)\"; fi"
```

Though, I suspect its not the best way to do what I need.
Any other way would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ssh host "num=\$(ls -1 /home/folder/anotherFolder | wc -l); if [ \$num -gt 3 ]; then echo yes: \$num; fi"
```

You need to escape the `$` symbols or they will be expanded on the local host.

Alternatively, use single quotes, then you don't have to escape the `$`:

```
ssh host 'num=$(ls -1 /home/folder/anotherFolder | wc -l); if [ $num -gt 3 ]; then echo yes: $num; fi'
```

Also, it is better practice to use `$(command)` format instead of `` `command` `` for command substitution.

Comment: This is only part of the whole ssh command. 
I want to use $num in another command in the same ssh session.
Assume that I want to check if num is greater than 3, and if it is, perform another operation on the remote compuert, all in a single ssh session.

Comment: Thanks. this helped a lot. I edited the question with the final outcome. Can you suggest a better way to achieve it?

Comment: A better way would be to create a script e.g. `deleteOldestFolder.sh` and invoke it in your ssh command. Otherwise your command becomes long, unreadable and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Any pipes and backticks which are not escaped will be evaluated on the current host. Therefore,

```
ssh host ls -1 /home/folder/anotherFolder | wc -l
```

means "Run `ls -1 /home/folder/anotherFolder` on the *other* host and count the lines on *this* host."

These commands all run `ls` and `wc` on the *current* host, and then assigns `num` to the result on the *other* host:

```
ssh host num=`ls -1 /home/folder/anotherFolder | wc -l`
ssh host num=`ls -1 "/home/folder/anotherFolder" | wc -l`
ssh host num=`ls -1 "/home/folder/anotherFolder" | wc -l`
```

Prototype fix:

```
num=$(ssh host "ls -1 /home/folder/anotherFolder" | wc -l)
```

meaning: Run `ls` on the other host, send all the data to this host, and run `wc` on that. Store the result of `wc` in `num`. @dogbane's solution is more effective, because it only sends back the count, not all the `ls` output.

**BUT**, [a better way](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to count the number of files is this:

```
num=$(ssh host "find /home/folder/anotherFolder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c")
```